# Python - Executar dois scripts ao mesmo tempo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Em tenho um arquivo `x.py` e o `y.py`, em outro arquivo eu tenho o seguinte código:

```py
import os

os.system('py -3.7 x.py')
os.system('py -3.7 y.py')
```

Mas o problema é que o `y.py` só executa quando a execução do `x.py` acaba, como eu poderia fazer para os dois executarem ao mesmo tempo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma biblioteca do Python para executar processos em paralelo é a [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html).

Basicamente, é possível declarar e executar um processo assim:

```
# Define um processo a partir de uma `função_a_ser_executada(arg1, arg2)`
processo = threading.Thread(target= função_a_ser_executada, args=(arg1, arg2, ))

# Inicia o processo
processo.start()
```

Para o seu caso, rodar scripts, a função a ser executada é a `inicia_programa(arquivo_nome)`. É preciso declarar um processo para cada arquivo (`x.py` e o `y.py`) e então iniciar os processos:

```
import threading
import os


def inicia_programa(nome_arquivo):
    os.system('py -3.7 {}'.format(nome_arquivo))
    # Ex: os.system('py -3.7 x.py')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    arquivos = ['x.py','y.py']

    processos = []
    for arquivo in arquivos:
        processos.append(threading.Thread(target=inicia_programa, args=(arquivo,)))
        # Ex: adicionar o porcesso `threading.Thread(target=inicia_programa, args=('x.py',))`

    for processo in processos:
        processo.start()
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!